# Are two equations equal

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I have a two  vector laplacians which have very long equations and I have to verify that they are equal, and doing that by hand would take an hour, I have tried using LHS == RHS, which should print True or False,  however, that is not working, it just prints both equations. Does anybody know how to solve this problem

Comment: `LHS == RHS // Simplify` or `LHS == RHS // FullSimplify` You may also need to add some assumptions. In general, include a minimal example that shows the problem you are having.

Comment: It's worth throwing in some numbers and check actual instances just to give you a warm and fuzzy that in fact your expressions are equal. Easy to insert a typo and then spend time trying to prove something that actually isn't true.

Comment: @BobHanlon the example is like x+y+z == z^2 +x-y and it just prints out that. I tried x+y+z == z^2+x-y //FullSimplify and that printed out x+y =0, I guess that means they are not equal.

Comment: Your example evaluates to `2 y + z == z^2`. If you got `x + y == 0` you  have some other definition hanging around.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. See the tag description for why. This is not a bug.